# Create a YouTube/Vimeo Type Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am going to show a list of SWF movies in a single DIV with a first SWF already as a default in the DIV, kind of like a photo gallery but with SWFs. Does anyone know have any pointers on this? I'd prefer this to be created using JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

jQuery Cycle can hold any type of content, include SWF files in a suitable player.

You can also check out http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

Both are jQuery plugins and configurable.